# Does the visual studio 2008 profiler work with unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I know that VS 2008 Team Edition has a profiler, but I'm also aware of the recent trend they have at Microsoft of completely ignoring unmanaged languages (what's the last time unmanaged C++ got something cool in the IDE?!).. For example I know for a fact that the IDE "Unit Tests" and "Code Metrics" features don't work with unmanaged code.

I tried to google but didn't find any info; so, does anyone know if it works or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it works with native code.

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried it and it does not produce any useful info.  For example, in the "Functions" view the source file name is shown as  for everything.  And yes I am building the release version and have turned on debug info (tried both /Z7 and /Zi).  I also tried both Instrumentation and Sampling methods with the same (non) results.

Answer (score 1):

My previous comment last something as stuff in < > was lost. Source files are shown as "Unknown" and I can only see the relative time in each module.  This is not a lot of use.  How do I get decent output?  (Give me TrueTime for VS2008!!)